# How to supress aliases errors in zsh?

Tags: zsh, alias

I want to have single list of aliases that I source to my .zshrc on all my computers and sync. But on one computer I have docker installed, and on another I don't. And every time I open terminal get an error:

```
/home/ubuntu/scripts/zsh_aliases:2: command not found: docker
```

... because I use docker in some aliases.

How do I suppress this inspection or redirect errors to log file?

It turned out this alias produce an error: `alias all.restart="docker restart $(docker ps -q)"`. I guess it is because of `$()`, but why?

Comment: It looks like you're *invoking* an alias, in order to generate that "command not found" error. Could you post the relevant portion of that file?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, I  added ```source ~/scripts/zsh_aliases``` to .zshrc. And alias is```alias d="docker" ```

Comment: That alone wouldn't do it; something is calling `docker` (or `d`) somewhere...

Comment: @JeffSchaller, turned out this alias produce an error```alias all.restart="docker restart $(docker ps -q)"``` I guess it is because of ```$()``, but why?

Comment: @ogbofjnr instead of using `command -v docker`, you could just escape the substitution : `alias all.restart="docker restart \$(docker ps -q)"`. this way, the `docker ps` part would be re-executed every time you run `all.restart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that invokes docker is producing that "command not found error"; from the comments, you have a line:

```
alias all.restart="docker restart $(docker ps -q)"
```

The `$(docker ...)` command substitution is invoking `docker`, which triggers your error when run on systems without docker.

Simply preface the alias with a check for the existence of the `docker` command:

```
command -v docker > /dev/null && alias all.restart="docker restart $(docker ps -q)"
```

The `command` command will fail if the `docker` command is not found, which will bypass the subsequent `&& alias` portion. If the `docker` command *does* exist, then the `alias` command is executed.